# Doing POST with AJAX returns "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

Tags: ajax, cors

I am getting a "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" everytime I try to execute a POST with AJAX into my webservice. I have downloaded a CORS plug in for my browser and I am able to execute a 'GET' request with it.

```
$(function(){
var $name = $("#nameTxtB");
var $order = $("#orderTxtB");
var $price = $("#priceTxtB");
var $link = "http://localhost:51834/CoffeeService.svc/addorder";

$("#addButton").on('click', function(){
var $try1 = $price.val();
var $parse = parseInt($try1);
console.log($parse);
var CoffeeOrders = {
Name: $name.val(),
Order: $order.val(),
Price: $parse,
  };
console.log(CoffeeOrders);

$.ajax({
 contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType : 'json',
 type: 'POST',
 url: $link,
 data: CoffeeOrders,

 success: function(){
 alert("Order was sucessfully created!");
 },
  error: function(){
  alert("Something went wrong!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needs to actually implement the CORS-preflight protocol if you want to make complicated requests like that. It's explained in the standard: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol.